# Format date with leading zeros in EF Core Linq GroupBy statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ef-core-3.1

I've a LINQ statement (EF Core 3.1) where I want to group by year and month of a timestamp column, e.g. "2020-03".

```
var result = _context.Messages
            .Where(x => x.timestamp != null)
            .GroupBy(x => x.timestamp.Value.Year.ToString()+"-" + x.timestamp.Value.Month.ToString())
            .Select(x => new { date = x.Key, count = x.Count() })
```

The problem is that the result format of date is "2020-3" which causes in later sorting problems.

How can I format the month string to always have 2 digits with a leading zero?

I read a lot about SqlFunctions - but these are not available in EF Core. Are there any other ways?

Comment: You should group by the actual fields and then deal with the formatting later or as an added property

Comment: From a sql perspective, not doing the data transphormation in the group by may help. Sql will be able to use the index on those column. You could then get those in memory and do the format. Only on the result. One format per distinct group vs one format per row. And using index instead of grouping on a newly created key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group by the actual year/month and then project out those values. This way the grouping gets done entirely in SQL. Once you have the in-memory collection, you could project again creating your sort key along with the [`D2` format specifer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-decimal-d-format-specifier)

```
var result = _context.Messages
            .Where(x => x.timestamp != null)
            .GroupBy(x => new { 
                x.timestamp.Value.Year,
                x.timestamp.Value.Month
             })
            .Select(x => new { 
                Year = x.Key.Year, 
                Month = x.Key.Month, 
                Count = x.Count() 
             })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => new {
                Date = $"{x.Year:D2}-{x.Month:D2}",
                Count = x.Count
             }) 
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect idea, to group in first place on the server and do the string formation afterwards in a second select :-) Works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format overload of `ToString()` method with value "d2". This way the format will make sure you always get two digits:

```
x.timestamp.Value.Month.ToString("d2")
```

Comment: This was also one of my ideas - but it failed an throws a runtime error, that the LINQ expression couldn't be converted into an SQL statement.